# side-effect of floating table header + rounded corners

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please refer to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KSZMy). While scrolling down, the table cells appear in the rounded corners. How do I hide that?

### Explanation

I have a table of data that when scrolled headers stay fixed, but data scrolls (using javascript).

The problem is that my headers have rounded corners and when my table gets scrolled cells appear in the rounded corner area as seen on the image below.

#### What should I do to avoid this?

[image]

Comment: I realize the question is much (MUCH!) easier to understand if you just look at the fiddle, but for this to be a real question, it really needs to describe the problem and provide sample code (not necessarily all, but the relevant parts). You have to imagine it being useful to future readers even if jsfiddle closes shop.

Comment: I will take care of that next time I ask a question. I thought that having a fiddle, it would be straight forward and easy to understand the problem. 
Thank you for your feedback though.

Comment: @rad: **Next time?** Why not edit existing question **now**? I did it this time for you, but even though your answer has been answered you should edit it appropriately because of history reasons.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik sorry about that, and thanks for doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match the background behind the elements to the body background:

```
thead tr { background: #fff; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/CDSdU/

Comment: Its gonna be a little messy because my website has a gradient background. :)

Answer (score 1):

Make the header's parent have a `background-color:white;` and then make sure that is the fixed element.